# Delphi RegExpo Incorrect Data

Tags: delphi, registry

Edit: Seems like it works fine if I run my app as an Admin

I am using the following

```
unit RegExpo;

interface

uses
Windows, Registry, Classes, SysUtils;

{$I-}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}

{

 Example:
 ExportRegistryBranch(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi','c:\DELPHI.REG')

}


procedure ExportRegistryBranch(RootSection: DWORD; RegRoot: string;
 FileName: string);

implementation


function dblBackSlash(t: string): string;
var
k: longint;
begin
Result := t; {Strings are not allowed to have}
for k := Length(t) downto 1 do {single backslashes}
if Result[k] = '\' then Insert('\', Result, k);
end;


procedure ExportRegistryBranch(RootSection: DWORD; RegRoot: string;
FileName: string);
var
 reg: TRegistry;
 f: Textfile;
 p: PChar;

procedure ProcessBranch(root: string); {recursive sub-procedure}
var
values, keys: TStringList;
i, j, k: longint;
s, t: string; {longstrings are on the heap, not on the stack!}
begin
WriteLn(f); {write blank line}
case RootSection of
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT: s   := 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT';
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER: s   := 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER';
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE: s  := 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE';
  HKEY_USERS: s          := 'HKEY_USERS';
  HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA: s := 'HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA';
  HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG: s := 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG';
  HKEY_DYN_DATA: s       := 'HKEY_DYN_DATA';
end;
WriteLn(f, '[' + s + '\' + root + ']'); {write section name in brackets}

reg.OpenKey(root, False);
try
  values := TStringList.Create;
  try
    keys := TStringList.Create;
    try
      reg.GetValuenames(values); {get all value names}
      reg.GetKeynames(keys); {get all sub-branches}

      for i := 0 to values.Count - 1 do {write all the values first}
      begin
        s := values[i];
        t := s; {s=value name}
        if s = '' then s := '@' {empty means "default value", write as @}
        else
          s := '"' + s + '"'; {else put in quotes}
        Write(f, dblbackslash(s) + '='); {write the name of the key to the file}

        case reg.Getdatatype(t) of {What type of data is it?}

          rdString, rdExpandString: {String-type}
            WriteLn(f, '"' + dblbackslash(reg.ReadString(t) + '"'));

          rdInteger: {32-bit unsigned long integer}
            WriteLn(f, 'dword:' + IntToHex(reg.readinteger(t), 8));

         {write an array of hex bytes if data is "binary." Perform a line feed
          after approx. 25 numbers so the line length stays within limits}

          rdBinary:
            begin
              Write(f, 'hex:');
              j := reg.GetDataSize(t); {determine size}
              GetMem(p, j); {Allocate memory}
              reg.ReadBinaryData(t, p^, J); {read in the data, treat as pchar}
              for k := 0 to j - 1 do
              begin
                Write(f, IntToHex(Byte(p[k]), 2)); {Write byte as hex}
                if k <> j - 1 then {not yet last byte?}
                begin
                  Write(f, ','); {then write Comma}
                  if (k > 0) and ((k mod 25) = 0) {line too long?} then
                    WriteLn(f, '\'); {then write Backslash +lf}
                end; {if}
              end; {for}
              FreeMem(p, j); {free the memory}
              WriteLn(f); {Linefeed}
            end;
          else
            WriteLn(f, '""'); {write an empty string if datatype illegal/unknown}
        end;{case}
      end; {for}
    finally
      reg.CloseKey;
    end;

  finally
    {value names all done, no longer needed}
    values.Free;
  end;

  {Now al values are written, we process all subkeys}
  {Perform this process RECURSIVELY...}
  for i := 0 to keys.Count - 1 do
    ProcessBranch(root + '\' + keys[i]);
finally
  keys.Free; {this branch is ready}
end;
end; { ProcessBranch}


begin
if RegRoot[Length(Regroot)] = '\' then {No trailing backslash}
SetLength(regroot, Length(Regroot) - 1);
AssignFile(f, FileName); {create a text file}
Rewrite(f);
if ioResult <> 0 then Exit;
//WriteLn(f, 'REGEDIT4'); {"magic key" for regedit}
WriteLn(f, 'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00');
reg := TRegistry.Create;
try
 reg.Rootkey := RootSection;
  {Call the function that writes the branch and all subbranches}
  ProcessBranch(Regroot);
  finally
  reg.Free; {ready}
  CloseFile(f);
end;
end;
```

end.

Seems like the only info I am getting no matter the Branch I try and save is the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\patches]
```

Any ideas on what I am missing or can someone recommend a better way to export a registry branch?

Comment: Might be easier to shell out to `reg` to do this

Comment: @David I have that working but wanted to have a function to do it in code not by using shellapi

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? Do you know how to use that? Since you wrote the code you must have an expectation of what it does. Do some debugger to work out where the code diverges from your expectation.

Comment: Honestly still learning Delphi and the whole process, kind of a trial by fire :-) so for this one no I have not used the debugger yet

Comment: Well, it's time for you to learn how to debug.

Comment: found the following: keys.FDefined [(out of bound) 5,(out of bound) 7] and Inaccessible value seems like a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that the code requests full access to the registry. Instead it needs to request read access:

```
reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
```

Answer (score 1):

The close of "reg.CloseKey;" is missing before open a new key.

```
Writeln(f, '[' + s + '\' + root + ']'); { write section name in brackets }

// open in readmode
reg.CloseKey;
reg.Access := KEY_READ;
reg.OpenKey(root, False);
```